# Display empty string on textbox disable

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I'm am trying to create a custom TextBox that display an empty string when it is disabled (Enabled = false).
When I enable it again, it should display the last value. Also, the Text property should always return the real value, even if it's disabled.

Here is what I have so far, but it's not really working as I want.

Can you help me figure out what is wrong?

```
public class TestTextBox: System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
{
    private string _text = string.Empty;
    public new string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return _text;
        }
        set
        {
            _text = value;
            base.Text = FormatValue(value);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnEnabledChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnEnabledChanged(e);

        base.Text = FormatValue(_text);
    }

    private string FormatValue(string text)
    {
        if(this.Enabled == true)
        {
            return text;
        }
        else
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is it doing wrong?

Comment: It won't go back to original text after I enable it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the mistake in the code is that typing in it doesn't change its `Text` property.

If you add a button with:

```
testTextBox1.Text = "It works";
```

then enabling and disabling the `TestTextBox` will toggle between empty and "It works".

EDIT

Add:

```
protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnTextChanged(e);
    if (Enabled)
        Text = base.Text;
}
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer!

Comment: @Pierre-OlivierGoulet I tested it. It works. (By the way, +1 on the question. non-trivial mistake there.)

Comment: Yeah, it works as long as I don't type in the textbox... How can I make it work also when typing?

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
protected override void OnEnabledChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnEnabledChanged(e);

    this.ForeColor = this.Enabled ? SystemColors.ControlText : this.BackColor;
}
```

If you want to support other ForeColors you can store the current one in a Property and use it instead of `SystemColors.ControlText`.

Comment: This is by far the simplest solution. You can also use Color.Transparent instead of this.BackColor

Comment: Yes, I have come to stay away from Transparency, but it ought to work here ;-)

Comment: While this wokrs, I'll keep it as a last resort because it is not 'politicaly correct'...

Comment: Well I thought so myself and in fact a spy tool would be able to read the text. But if that's the concern I guess that solution will be the least of your concerns. Being disabled the text can't be selected either, which would make it visible, so i guess it is safe enough.